# PHP Image colour gradient is not displayed correctly

Tags: php, image, colors, background, gradient

I am currently programming a background-image using PHP with a color gradient for all browsers that do not support CSS3. I have got the following code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$from=array("R"=>255, "G"=>255, "B"=>255);
$to=array("R"=>170, "G"=>221, "B"=>255);

$width=500;
$height=1000;
$image=imagecreate($width, $height);
for($y=0; $y < $height; $y++)
{
    imageline($image, 0, $y, $width, $y, imagecolorallocate($image, $from["R"]-(($from["R"]-$to["R"])/$height)*$y, $from["G"]-(($from["G"]-$to["G"])/$height)*$y, $from["B"]-(($from["B"]-$to["B"])/$height)*$y));
}
imagepng($image);
?>
```

It seems to be so simple but I really do not know why the image is not displayed correctly. It is shown as you can see below but the gradient should be 1000px high.
[image: The gradient that is displayed]

Comment: There are not enough items in your array to span the 1000 pixels height. You need to scale the whole thing. Can you use ImageMagick? It would be easier there.

Comment: But why should this play any role? Using the expression "(($from["R"]-$to["R"])/$height)" I calculate the size of a color step size. My $y is the number of the current step. At the last repeat of the for-loop $y will be $height-1. Say the condition of my for-loop would be $y <= $height then I could just cancel out $y and $height.

Comment: I see, you are already taking that into account. Hmm, then there must be some flaw in that logic... I can't spot it right now. Maybe try debugging the R value and seeing where it "breaks". The gradient, at any rate, seems 255 Pixels tall and I'm 100% sure that has to do with the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem. The function "imagecolorallocate" seems to be restricted to a limited number of calls. I used "imagecolorresolve" instead and it works fine. Another option is using "imagecreatetruecolor" for creating the image. Then you can use "imagecolorallocate".